# Array modifier to achieve a partial object (ie. non-integer objects)?

Tags: modifiers

I often need a long string of objects followed by a variable size partial object at the end.  For example, a long line of brick objects.  There are times that I want an array 15.45 (for example) items long.  Any thoughts on how to do this without a second object that I just slice and append to the end?

Thanks for your help!
Erik

Comment: Boolean modifier with a hidden cube as the target?

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this with a little overhead:

1. you created your array of e.g. a cube
2. you double that cube (before you add the array modifier)
3. you shorten the cube in edit mode as you need
4. you add that edited cube as cap end in the array modifier like here:

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  I really like that this keeps everything together in a single array.  What I'm hoping to avoid is the overhead ;). And the ability to have varying dimensions of that end cap.